# What does the await keyword do in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-3.5

Python 3.5 with [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) introduces special syntax for coroutines and *awaitables* and illustrates the `await` keyword as follows:

> The following new await expression is used to obtain a result of coroutine execution:
>
> ```
> async def read_data(db):
>     data = await db.fetch('SELECT ...')
>     ...
> ```
>
> `await`, similarly to `yield from`, suspends execution of `read_data` coroutine until `db.fetch` awaitable completes and returns the result data.

It continues to define that *awaitables* can be coroutines or Future-like objects, with a specific definition of Future-like objects.
But despite reading the PEP, I don't quite understand what's special about `await`.  In the line quoted from the PEP above, who returns the result data — `await` or `read_data` (or both)?  Surely no matter how I call `db.fetch('SELECT ...')` (directly, with `yield from`, or with `await`), `read_data` will not continue until it gets something (possibly `None`) from `db.fetch`?  Then what's special about `await` and how is it related to `async`?

Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: Huh, that question wasn't there when I started writing mine...

Comment: `yield from` *delegates* to another generator. If that other generator just yields *I'm not ready* signals, an event handler can move on to iterating over another generator. Co-routines formalise that behaviour; `await` passes on the *I'm not ready* signal, or executes the inner-most co-routine if it is actually ready to do something.

Comment: Nope, the two of you coincided quite closely in asking your questions.

Comment: `await` will suspend execution of `read_data` until the results are actually ready. In this context, "suspending execution" means that control will be returned to an event loop, which will continue to run other callbacks (or wait for something interesting to happen). Once database results are ready, `await` will make sure that the data (as opposed to a "Future" object) is returned.